# Getting a double complex that computes Ext

Tags: homological-algebra

Suppose $C$ is an abelian category and I am trying to compute $Ext^i(M,N)$ for some objects $M,N$. Suppose there is an exact sequence

$0 \rightarrow A_1 \rightarrow A_2 ... \rightarrow A_n \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$.

Is it possible to get a double complex where the rows are

$0 \rightarrow Ext^i(A_n,N) \rightarrow ... \rightarrow Ext^i(A_1,N) 
\rightarrow 0$

and where the vertical rows are $\{Ext^*(A_i,N)\}$, such that the spectral sequence of the double sequence converges to $Ext^*(M,N)$?

I was reading a paper and the author seems to have done this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spectral sequence is not exactly what you said (there would be no vertical rows). In fact, it is one of the [hypercohomology spectral sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperhomology), and you described exactly the $E_1$-page.

Let me change the order of your exact sequence so that I get the indices right. So you have a exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow A_n\rightarrow\dots\rightarrow A_0\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0.$$
This can be seen as an quasi-isomorphism of complexes $A_*\rightarrow M[0]$ where $M[0]$ is the complex with $M$ concentrated in degree 0.

Because hypercohomology is invariant by quasi-isomorphism, there is an isomorphism $$\operatorname{Ext}^i(M,N)\overset{\sim}\rightarrow\mathbb{Ext}^i(A_*,N)$$
and now the hypercohomology spectral sequence takes the form $$E_1^{pq}=\operatorname{Ext}^q(A_p,N)\Rightarrow \mathbb{Ext}^{p+q}(A_*,N)$$